# Reverse n characters in the string (there is no spaces in string) without using built-in functions in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string like str="**ABCDEFGHIJK**";

need o/p like this str="CBAFEDIHGJK"

am getting "CBA" correctly after that its not printing anything.

can anyone check the following code and let me know where is the problem?

```
int main()

  {
   string str="ABCDEFGHIJK";

    char str1[10],rev[10];

   int n=str.length(),count=0,c=3,k=0,j=0;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     str1[i]=str[i];
     count++;

     cout<<str1[i]<<" and "<<count<<"and "<<c<<endl;

     if(count==c)
     {
        cout<<"Entered into if loop"<<count<<"and"<<c<<"and "<<k<<endl;

        cout<<c<<" and "<<k<<endl;
        while(j<c)
        {
            rev[j]=str1[c-k-1];

            cout<<rev[j]<<" and "<<str1[c-k-1]<<endl;
            j++;
             k++;
        }

          count=0; 
     }
    /*else
    {
      if(count < c && str[i]=='\0')
      {
        for(int k=0;k<count;k++)
         {
           rev[k]=str1[count-1];

           count--;
           count=0;
         }
      }
    }*/
  }

   cout<<"The string is: "<<rev<<endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Your program seems to be using some C++ features, not C.

Comment: make sure your strings are long enough to contain (`11 + '\0'`)

Comment: You need to set `j = 0` before the `while (j < c)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a c++ `string` object for this use-case; just use a normal `char *`.

Also, always make sure you store enough room for the string *null-terminator* character (`'\0'`). This is required as c string functions assume your string is terminated in this way.

Following will reverse string in ansi C89

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *in, char *rev)
{
  int i, n;

  n = strlen(in);

  for(i = n-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    rev[n-i-1] = in[i];
  }
  /* add the null-terminator */
  rev[n] = '\0';

}

int main()
{
  char *str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
  char str1[12], temp;
  char triplet[4];
  char rev_triplet[4];

  int index;

  triplet[3] = '\0';
  rev_triplet[3] = '\0';
  str1[0] = '\0';
  for(index = 0; index < strlen(str); index += 3)
  {
    memcpy(triplet, str + index, 3 * sizeof(char));
    reverse(triplet, rev_triplet);
    strcat(str1, rev_triplet);
  }

  printf("Initial string is: %s\n", str);
  printf("Reverse string is: %s\n", str1);
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
$ ./test
Initial string is: ABCDEFGHIJK
Reverse string is: CBAFEDIHGKJ
```

Comment: output is not like that, it should be CBAFEDIHGJK, "JK" is printing as it is because I took no. of character are 3 only so they wont reverse.

Comment: updated to reverse triplets, if you dont want `"JK"` reversed, would just update the `index < strlen(str)` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use C++ (and not C) for this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse_triples(std::string s)
{
    const unsigned int N = 3;
    for (int i = 0, j = N - 1; i < s.length() - (s.length() % N); i += N, j += N)
    {
        std::swap(s[i], s[j]);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    std::string rs = reverse_triples(s);
    std::cout << "Reversed Triples:  " << rs << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever value of `N` you need can be modified (and even supplied as a function parameter if you want).  You only need to swap the outer characters (so all the elements below `N / 2` will be swapped with the elements above `N / 2`).  For `N == 3`, it is just a single swap.  If you want to do it more generically:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse_substrings(std::string s, unsigned int substring_size)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = substring_size - 1; i < s.length() - (s.length() % substring_size); i += substring_size, j += substring_size)
    {
        std::reverse(s.begin() + i, s.begin() + j + 1);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    std::string rs = reverse_triples(s, 4); // passing 3 gets you the same results as before
    std::cout << "Reversed Triples:  " << rs << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let us examine how `std::reverse` might be implemented. It uses iterators.

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
  void reverse (BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
  while ((first!=last)&&(first!=--last)) {
    std::iter_swap (first,last);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

We can extend the logic to use indices instead of iterators, where `i` and `j` represent iterators (positions) and `s[i]` and `s[j]` represent the data pointed to by the iterators.

```
void reverse(std::string& s)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.size();
    while ((i != j) && (i != (--j))) 
    {
        std::swap(s[i], s[j]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Now you want to reverse "chunks" rather than the entire string.

```
void reverse(int n, std::string& s)
{
    int beg = 0;
    int end = beg + n;
    int size = s.size();

    // We're going to modify s in place
    // So store a copy
    std::string copy = s;
    s = "";

    // Add + 1 to avoid the loop cutting off short
    // Or do i <= size / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / n + 1; i++)
    {
        std::string chunk(copy.begin() + beg, copy.begin() + end);

        // If there's no n sized chunks left
        // don't reverse
        if (end < size)
            reverse(chunk);
        s += chunk;
        beg += n;

        // Don't go past the size of the string
        end += (end + n > size ? size - end : n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("ABCDEFGHIJK");
    std::string target("CBAFEDIHGJK");

    reverse(3, s);
    std::cout << s << "|" << target <<"|\n";
    std::cout << s.size() << " " << target.size() << "\n"; // 11 11
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (s == target); // true
    return 0;
}
```